# Screen has shifted down in Windows 7

Tags: resolution

Looks like the baby has been pounding the keyboard again. The enter screen has shifted down a quarter of an inch. This has happened before but i can't remember what i did to fix it.

I tried changing to 1600x1200 and it goes full screen but when i change it back to 1680x1050 is gets jacked up.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by the "enter screen"? Also, what type of input are you using? DVI? HDMI? VGA? S-Video?

Comment: For the "baby pounding the keyboard" issue, there is "Baby Smash!": http://www.hanselman.com/babysmash/ :-)

Comment: he's fond of babysmash especially when it's not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an **Auto** button on your monitor?  Sometimes this will fix screen positioning problems.

Comment: Issue resolved. I kept hitting the auto button until it worked..kinda liked what the baby did. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess this is on a laptop.  I'm also going to guess that you mean 'entire screen'.

If that is the case, I've seen this happen on certain models of some brands of laptops when you put it in 'Presentation Mode' without an external display hooked up. Basically it's because some of the built-in graphics drivers get a little confused when you change their profile settings.

Seek out your <kbd>Fn</kbd> and the key (usually <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>F9</kbd>) that is for switching to your external display.  The symbol on it usually looks like two rounded rectangles.

Sometimes it takes a combination of this key sequence and closing/reopening your laptop screen to set things right.

Comment: Hey guys..im on a desktop and the input is VGA.

There is a black bar at the top of the screen and the bottom task bar is gone because it has been pushed down the same amount as the top.